# Is "/proc/<pid>/map_files" include mapped file of all tid or just include mapped file of tid=pid only?

Tags: linux-kernel, proc

There is `/proc/pid/task/tid/maps` file but no corresponding `/proc/pid/task/tid/map_files`.

Comment: But all the threads share the same memory space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All tids share the same memory, so the maps file will include all of them